# what does [ConfigurationProperty("providers")] do?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

I am reading this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/webmaster3/ProviderPattern12242007184126PM/ProviderPattern.aspx) on provider patren. Kindly guide me what do this statement:

```
 [ConfigurationProperty("providers")]
```

Actually I want to learn what is [] ? I also saw such a line on web methods with []. What are [] ? what is there use ? I am even not aware to search what I should name it ? plz guide and help me.

Thanks

Comment: It's the C# syntax for decorating code with attributes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28VS.80%29.aspx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[Foo(bla)]` is the syntax for an attribute - additional metadata about some type or member (or even the assembly itself; or indeed parameters). You can write your own attributes, for example that one is something like:

```
public class ConfigurationPropertyAttribute : Attribute {
    public ConfigurationPropertyAttribute(string something) {...}
}
```

the name `Attribute` is inferred, so only `[ConfigurationProperty]` is needed. The string `"providers"` is used as a constructor argument, and also you can use property assignments, for example:

```
[Foo(123, "abc", Bar = 123)]
```

looks for a type `FooAttribute` or `Foo`, with a constructor that takes an `int` and a `string`, and has a property `Bar` that can be assigned an `int`.

Most attributes don't do anything **directly**, but you can write code that *inspects* types for attributes (via reflection), which is a very convenient way of library code knowing how to work with a type.

For example:

```
[XmlType("abc"), XmlRoot("abc")]
public class MyType {
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string UserName {get;set;}
}
```

this reconfigures `XmlSerializer` (which checks for the above attributes) to serialize the type as:

```
<abc name="blah"/>
```

where without the attributes it would be:

```
<MyType><UserName>blah</UserName></MyType>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing something to read settings from the web or app .config, you can create a configuration section. This is where declaring the `ConfigurationProperty` comes in.

Check out  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationpropertyattribute(v=VS.100).aspx